# display image from django model to template using for loop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

so i want to show the image of the product from the the Product model to the template in a table but the code below that i wrote shows the broken image sign at the image and does not work 
**here is my code** :

**in models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):

    Name = models.CharField(max_length=700, null=True)
    Price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    Link = models.URLField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    Image = models.ImageField(null=True)
```

**in my views.py** :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *


def home(request):

    Products = Product.objects.all()


    context = {'products':Products}
    return render(request, 'Cam/main.html', context)
```

**in the template (the html file):**

```
<div class="container ">

    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr class="row">
          <th class="col-md-1" >Name</th>
          <th class="col " >Picture</th>
          <th class="col-md-1" >Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead> 
      <tbody>

        {% for product in products %}

        <tr class="row">
          <td class="col-md-1"> {{product.Name}} </td>
          <td class="col-md-1"><img id="IMG" src="{{product.Image.url}}" ></td> 
          <td class="col-md-1"> {{product.Price}} </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/, also are you sure image is uploaded correctly. Additionally model field names should be written snake case not capitalized

Comment: yes i think the images are uploaded correctly and they transformed automatically to the project file after uploading them and not on the static/images file is that okey ?

Comment: When you inspect element do you see correct URL, also docs are not only regarding static files but also media files  /#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: when i check the admin page and check the image field i see the correct urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're not following Python convention: A class should be Capitalized (Pascal Case) and an attribute should be a lowercase :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=700, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True)
```

To answer the question, make sure you have done the followings:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # urls/path
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Template

```
<img src="{{ product.image.url }}">
```

Model:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'product-img/', null=True)
```

If the image is saved, you'll find it in folder media/product-img

Comment: Thank you so much , that was helpful